# HSQLDB “precision or scale out of range” and "user lacks privilege or object not found" error when hibernate hbm2ddl import files

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb

I cannot figure it out what I am doing wrong.

**Schema.sql** is just to show how **HSQLDB** see the table.

I don't have any idea. Am I just maybe blind or...

Error I have pointing to '**precision or scale out of range**':

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: precision or scale out of range
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: precision or scale out of range
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTypeDefinition(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.readColumnDefinitionOrNull(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.readTableContentsSource(Unknown Source)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

This is entity:

```
@Entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE", schema = "MY_SCHEMA", catalog = "")
public class MyTable {
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, precision = 0)
private long id;
@Basic
@Column(name = "STR1", nullable = true, length = 2265)
private String str1;
@Basic
@Column(name = "STR2", nullable = true, length = 1000)
private String str2;
@Basic
@Column(name = "NUM1", nullable = false, precision = 0)
private long num1;
@Basic
@Column(name = "STR3", nullable = true, length = 100)
private String str3;
@Basic
@Column(name = "NUM2", nullable = true, precision = 0)
private Long num2;
@Basic
@Column(name = "STR4", nullable = true, length = 36)
private String str4;
@Basic
@Column(name = "STR5", nullable = true, length = 250)
private String str5;
@Basic
@Column(name = "DT1", nullable = false)
private Time dt1;
@Basic
@Column(name = "DT2", nullable = true)
private Time dt2;
@Basic
@Column(name = "NUM3", nullable = true, precision = 0)
private Long num3;
@Basic
@Column(name = "STR6", nullable = true, length = 100)
private String str6;
@Basic
@Column(name = "STR7", nullable = true, length = 36)
private String str7;
@Basic
@Column(name = "STR8", nullable = true, length = 254)
private String str8;
}
```

My **schema.sql** looks like:

```
create table MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (
ID bigint not null, STR7 varchar(36), STR6 varchar(100), NUM3 bigint not null, STR8 varchar(254), STR4 varchar(36),
STR5 varchar(250) not null, NUM2 bigint, STR1 varchar(2265), STR2 varchar(1000), DT2 time, DT1 time,
STR3 varchar(100), NUM1 bigint, primary key (ID))
```

My **data.sql** looks like:

```
Insert into MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE(ID,STR7,STR6,NUM3,STR8,STR4,STR5,NUM2,STR1,STR2,DT2,DT1,STR3,NUM1)
values (1234567,'str7','str6',1,'str8','str4','str5',12345,'str1','str2',null,null,'str3',12345);
```

And my code is:

```
jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create");
jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_IMPORT_FILES, "data.sql.old");
jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.database-product-name", "HSQL");
jpaProperties.put("jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes", "true");
jpaProperties.put("jadira.usertype.databaseZone", "jvm");
jpaProperties.put("jadira.usertype.javaZone", "jvm");
```

My **pom.xml** is spring-boot.version>2.0.4.RELEASE:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId> <- 1.4.197
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
  <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId> <- 2.4.1
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE**

I change code and I added oracle **dialect** property to jpa:

```
jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT,"org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
....
jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.database-product-name", "HSQL");
```

It generate a little bit different schema, oracle look like but now I have a new issue.
Now everything goes fine. It insert from script. At least I don't have any error so I guess it was inserted. But when I try to see that, to use jpa and for example findAll() it returns new error:

```
WARN: SQL Error: -5501, SQLState: 42501
Mar 18, 2020 11:42:51 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: user lacks privilege or object not found: VW_ECONF_ATTACHEMENT in statement [select myTable0_.ID as ID1_0_, myTable0_.STR1 as STR12_0_, ..., myTable_.STR8 as STR814_0_ from MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE myTable_]
```

Should I add username and password?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do and how you are trying to do. Just pasting code is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Precision cannot be 0 for a long, I don't you need to define it all

Comment: Entity is something generated by IntelliJ from Oracle DB. Now I am trying to have in memory HSQL database. With code it generate schema.sql form that entity and this is how HSQL see it. Then I try to insert row but I have this error.

Comment: I added oracle dialect so now it created oracle look like schema and now i have different issue.